# How can I get rid of Working Joes?

Tags: alien-isolation

There are multiple moments in Alien Isolation when I have to deal with Working Joes. They are hard to kill with the revolver, especially when there are more than one. Fire doesn't seem to be very effective either.

Which strategy is effective against them?

Answer (score 7):

Against these, 4 things are quite effective in my experience:

#### 1. Pipe Bombs

Makes them magically disappear. Easy to build since the components aren't that rare (at least i found tons of them) and very effective since one well placed one is enough to take several of these guys straight into robotic heaven.

**Disadvantages:** Loud, might attract the alien. Or no, not might. WILL attract the alien.

#### 2. EMPs

Disables them for a short duration in which you can either avoid them or kill them in any way to like. After they are reactivated, they will act like nothing happened unless you are near them.

**Disadvantages:** Compenents for those are rare and it's also quite loud

#### 3. Melee Attacks

Not much to say, use your weapon to take them out.

**Disadvantages:** Takes a while and is dangerous since the joe might be able to grab you.

#### 4. Avoid them

Probably the best way. There are only a few situations in the game where you have to fight them, but in general, you can sneak past them without being noticed. This is silent, won't attract anyone, so perfect.

**Disadvantages:** Limits you in free exploring since there always are threats around you.